# ¿Es posible simplificar este codigo utilizando vectores en C++?

Tags: c++

La idea es que sume todos los importes de un fichero existente para que me diga cual es el total de caja. Ejemplo 600, 300, 200, -100. EL importe total de caja es: X. Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera (poniendo como limite hasta 28 importes posibles)

```
void Menu141(int numero1, int numero2, int numero3, int numero4, int numero5, int numero6, int numero7,
    int numero8, int numero9, int numero10, int numero11, int numero12, int numero13, int numero14, int numero15,
    int numero16, int numero17, int numero18, int numero19, int numero20, int numero21, int numero22, int numero23,
    int numero24, int numero25, int numero26, int numero27, int numero28, int numero29)
    {
    ifstream leer;
    leer.open("librodiario.txt");
    char linea[50];
    leer.getline(linea,sizeof(linea));
    while(!leer.eof()){
    for(int i =  0;i<28;i++){
    char *puntero;
    if(i==0){
    puntero = strtok(linea,",");
    numero1 = atoi(puntero);
    }
    else if(i==1)
    {puntero = strtok(NULL,",");
    numero2 = atoi(puntero);
    }
    else if(i==2)
    {puntero = strtok(NULL,",");
    numero3 = atoi(puntero);
    }
    else if(i==3)
    {puntero = strtok(NULL,",");
    numero4 = atoi(puntero);
    }
    else if(i==4)
    {puntero = strtok(NULL,",");
    numero5 = atoi(puntero);
    }
    else if(i==5)
    {puntero = strtok(NULL,",");
    numero6 = atoi(puntero);
    }

    y asi sucesivamente hasta el numero 27
    }

    }

    numero29 = numero1+numero2+numero3+numero4+numero5+numero6+numero7+numero8+numero9+
    numero10+numero11+numero12+numero13+numero14+numero15+numero16+numero17+numero18+numero19+numero20+
    numero21+numero22+numero23+numero24+numero25+numero26+numero27+numero28;
    cout << "\n El total en caja, incluyendo el cambio tiene que ser de: " << numero29 << endl;
    leer.getline(linea,sizeof(linea));
    leer.close();
```

Existe manera de simplificarlo ya sea utilizando vectores o algun instrumento, del cual no tengo idea?

Comment: Puedes hacer uso de una variable acumuladora: ```C                while(!leer.eof())
    {  
       for(int i = 0; i < 28; i++) total += atoi(strtok(linea, ","));
    }```

Comment: De acuerdo creo que el usuario eferion amplio sobre eso en la respuesta de abajo. Se trata de la funcion standard accumulate, cierto?

Answer (score 2):

Analizando el código podemos ver que realmente no es necesario facilitarle ningún parámetro a la función. Podría ser la propia función la que se encargase de crear y devolver el array:

```
std::vector<int> Menu141(void)
{
  std::vector<int> toReturn;

  // ...

  toReturn;
}
```

Por otro lado, no es necesario leer el archivo línea a línea... podemos leer de entero en entero y vamos descartando por el camino los separadores, ya que no nos interesan:

```
ifstream leer;
leer.open("librodiario.txt");

for( size_t i=0; i<28; ++i )
{
    int numero;
    leer >> numero;
    leer.ignore(1); // Descartamos el separador
    toReturn.push_back(numero);
}

leer.close();

cout << "\n El total en caja, incluyendo el cambio tiene que ser de: "
     << std::accumulate(toReturn.begin(), toReturn.end(), 0) << endl;
```

`std::accumulate` es una función de la librería estándar que suma valores en un rango dado. El equivalente *a pelo* podría quedar así:

```
int total = 0;
for( int numero : toReturn )
  total += numero;

cout << "\n El total en caja, incluyendo el cambio tiene que ser de: "
     << total << endl;
```

Comment: Hola. No logro comprender del todo,pero Por lo que estuve investigando, estas utilizando la libreria standard, y para ello necesito saber sobre templates. Voy a leer sobre eso y volvere a comentar. Podrias indicarme  si hay algun concepto mas que tengo que estudiar para comprender tu codigo?

Comment: Ya pude entender tu codigo estudiando vectores. Gracias totales. ya esta funcional

Answer (score 0):

Asi puedes usar un array. Tambien puedes sumar los numeros entre el bucle for.

```
void Menu141(int [] numeros) {
    ifstream leer;
    leer.open("librodiario.txt");
    char linea[50];
    leer.getline(linea,sizeof(linea));
    while(!leer.eof()){
    char *puntero;
    puntero = strtok(linea,",");
    int sum = 0;
    numeros[0] = atoi(puntero);
    sum += numeros[0];
    for(unsigned int i = 1;i < numeros.size();i++){
       puntero = strtok(NULL,",");
       numeros[i] = atoi(puntero);
       sum += numeros[i];
    }
    cout << "\n El total en caja, incluyendo el cambio tiene que ser de: " << sum << endl;
    leer.getline(linea,sizeof(linea));
    leer.close();
```

EDICIONES: Lo edite para funcionar con qualquier tamaño.

Comment: Nota que en C++, los arrays **no tienen** métodos, luego la llamada a `size()` no compilará jamás

Comment: Hola Jacob. No logre compilar tu codigo en C++. :( Es posible adaptarlo de alguna manera para que funcione?

Comment: La respuesa sigue teniendo un problema... que has arrastrado de la pregunta original: Si hay un número entre las posiciones 49 y 50 de la línea, tu algortimo lo tratará como dos números independientes...